# Can I make text-file read-only forever?

Tags: encryption, gedit, 17.04, read-only

So I have encrypted gedit file, containing very sensitive information. Can I make it `read-only` forever? Yes, I know that I can do it in properties, but someone can change this to `read and write` and it's bypassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `chattr`, "chattr" is a utility to change file attributes:

```
sudo chattr +i filename
```

From `man chattr`:

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file.
>          Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Now no one can change this file, if you want no one ever get the chance to modify this file even in a live session then I suggest you to encrypt the whole filesystem.

Comment: You're welcome, Glad that I could help :)

Comment: This will not work with a FAT file system.

Comment: @b_laoshi Not only FAT, it's not going to work on any of none-native Linux filesystems.